# Table rows with identifying parameter in each row SQL SERVER 2008 into single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Sorry - my question title is probably as inept at my attempt to do this.

I have the following (well, similar) in a table in a CMS

```
pageID    key            value    

201       title          Page 201's title
201       description    This is 201
201       author         Dave
301       title          Page 301's title
301       description    This is 301
301       author         Bob
```

As you've probably guessed, what I need is a query that will produce:

```
pageID   title              description        author

201      Page 201's title   This is page 201   Dave
301      Page 301's title   This is page 301   Bob
```

If anybody could help, i'd be eternally grateful - I know this is "please send me the code" but I'm absolutely stuck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

Comment: Thanks Mark - will have a look when my brain's functioning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick hack may be

```
select a.pageID, a.value as Title, b.value as Description, c.value as Author from Table a
    left outer join Table b on a.pageID = b.pageID and b.key = 'description'
    left outer join Table c on a.pageID = c.pageID and c.key = 'author'
where a.key = 'title'
```

May not be the best solution, but it may work for you.

Comment: Thanks Francisco - I tried this but each field was filled with it's alias name instead of the value? May be I did it wrong though. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: No, i wrote it wrong, change the SELECT instead of a.key, b.key, c.key type a.value, etc, etc. My bad, sorry.

Comment: Yes it works! I've set this as the answer as it seems more robust. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

```
Select PageId
    , Min( Case When key = 'title' Then Value End ) As Title
    , Min( Case When key = 'description' Then Value End ) As Description
    , Min( Case When key = 'author' Then Value End ) As Author
From Table
Group By PageId
```

Comment: Hi Thomas - that's it! Thanks very much indeed!!

Comment: Thomas, this works perfectly, but I've marked Fransisco's answer - see comments. Thanks anyway - I've learned something from you both.